# sync files with potentially different contents but same names!

Tags: rsync, backup

I backup some photo directories on my phone into a folder on a Linux machine like this:

```
rsync -rtvu source_dir/  destination_dir/
```

It works very well, the destination directory could contain hundreds of files, but only a few new ones from the source are copied over.

Anyway, I just tried the same command with an old camcorder I rarely use and noticed that it does not name the files in a sensible way like the phone, including a date or timestamp, but gives them non-unique names like this:

```
00000.MTS  00004.MTS  00008.MTS  00012.MTS  00016.MTS  00020.MTS
00001.MTS  00005.MTS  00009.MTS  00013.MTS  00017.MTS  00021.MTS
00002.MTS  00006.MTS  00010.MTS  00014.MTS  00018.MTS  00022.MTS
00003.MTS  00007.MTS  00011.MTS  00015.MTS  00019.MTS
```

I had planned on emptying this SD card, and filming something else but this backup command is not fool-proof I don't think - rsync looks at the file names not the contents of the files I think.

Is this true? Can one get rsync to say check the hash of the files for similarity and rename them otherwise, or is there another appropriate solution?

Comment: rsync focuses on files that have changed in size or last-modified time

Comment: so will it overwrite a file with the same name but totally different content and a newer date?

Comment: As far as I know yes. Changes in data bytes would normally be dealt with by a file system syncing tool such as drbd.